# What is the opposite of free intended as "without"?

Tags: antonyms, suffixes

"Sugar free, taste *_*_"

Which word could I use to tell the opposite of "free" intended as "without"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, but often you can add *-y*, *-ed*, or *-full*. Sometimes you need a bit of circumlocution or periphrasis.

- *content-free* > *content-full* (but not **contented*! :)
- *sugar-free* > *sugary, sugared, with sugar*
- *taste-free* > *tasty, taste-full, full of taste*
- *additive-free* > *with additives*